# Navigate Component Tree inside a ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

We have the following structure in our xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat ...>
  ...
  <h:selectOneMenu ...>
  ...
    <p:ajax event="change" update="@parent:@parent" process="@parent:@parent" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:repeat ...>
```

In the event handler we get access to to the UiComponent representing the selectOneMenu. We can navigate to the parent, representing the ui:repeat. When looking at the children I'd expect to see all the selectOneMenu visible on the webpage, but I only see a single on. The one which triggered the change event.

How can I access the sibling components unter the ui:repeat component?

Motivation:

We basically create a grouped table. I.e. a table which is grouped into sections with data that belongs together. The code above creates one group. Certain values in the selectOneMenu must be selected for exactly one entry in a group. So when one value changes we have to access all entries in the same group to check if the constraint is fullfilled and to display error messages on the violating fields otherwise.

How it looks in the browser:

```
table: there is another outer repeat for creating the contents of this table
..group 1: content of each group is created by the ui:repeat
....row with selectOnMenu
....row with selectOnMenu
....row with selectOnMenu
....row with selectOnMenu
..group 2: content of each group is created by the ui:repeat
....row with selectOnMenu
....row with selectOnMenu
....row with selectOnMenu
....
```

row with selectOnMenu

How it looks in the event handler:

```
UiRepeat --> SelectOneMenu(exactly one)
```

Comment: Each of your `h:selectOneMenu` needs to be binded to a server-side model, given by its `value` attribute. Don't you have enough with it or you need also to get the UIComponent instance specifically? What are you looking for in the UIComponent?

Comment: we need the UIComponent, because we want to attach validation messages to it. I'd also like to understand if it is normal that we only see the one component or if we are doing something special/wrong, just to understand JSF better.

Comment: Ajax requests are able to send different form parts. That's what you define in your `f:ajax execute=""` or `p:ajax process=""` attributes. As they are defaulted to `@this`, only current component (`h:selectOneMenu`) is sent to process, so switching it to `@form` could be the key for your issue. BTW, are you using `h:selectOneMenu` with `p:ajax` for any specific reason? You should use either `f:ajax` if vanilla JSF or `p:selectOneMenu` if want to do it all with Prime.

Comment: @XtremeBiker the process attribute should cover all the selectOneMenus I think. I updated the code in the question. The reason to mix h: and p: is not very specific. p:selectOneMenu just looked really ugly.

Comment: Then go with `f:ajax`. That's the tag for JSF components.

Comment: Anyway, I thing you can achieve what you're looking for in a much easier way. You want just to display an error message near the field when user sends the form, if not properly filled? Don't think you need to do such a complicated stuff for this.

Comment: @XtremeBiker No, I want to do put an error message (or remove it) next to fields (a)+(b) when field (a) got changed.

Comment: Well, what are fields (a)+(b)? Are they going in pairs? Now I understand nothing :-( It good be helpful to provide a clearer example narrowing the problem.

Comment: @XtremeBiker fields a + b are two sibling instances of the selectOneMenu. I extended the question description in an attempt to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

Components like `ui:repeat` and `h:dataTable` use an approach called *stamping* to process child content. This means that the child components only exist **once** regardless of the number of items in the collection referenced in `value`. When the component is processed, JSF reuses this component(s) for every item in the collection (when you look at the rendered HTML, you can see the index in the ID). With this approach the size of the component tree is the same if you have one or 1000 items in your collection.

The above is just the explanation for the behavior you noticed. Regarding your problem there might be multiple solutions depending on the exact requirements and the way your data is structured.

You could do the validation in a listener you specify on the `p:ajax` tag triggering the request (assuming you can *find* the data for the current group in the model). This listener is executed in phase 5 of the lifecycle. If the ajax requests submits the current group, the data should be available in the model already.

You can then add validation error messages for a specific component like this:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ctx.addMessage("clientId of Component",
               new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Your message", null));
```

One way to get the clientIDs of the submitted components is a system event listener for the `preValidate` event on your `h:selectOneMenu`:

```
<f:event type="preValidate" listener="#{page.preValidate}"/>
```

In the listener method you can then access the client id of the current component (including the index of the current item!):

```
public void preValidate(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
  String clientId = event.getComponent().getClientId();
}
```

This listener is then called for all submitted components. Additionally, you would somehow have to map this clientId to the current item in the model (get the index of the parent `ui:repeat` component for instance).

The above are only some basic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your behavior and Micha's answer you should use

```
<c:forEach>
```

Instead of

```
 <ui:repeat>
```

.  ForEach will generate all components you need.